# Min and Max of a keys in a Python Dictionary of Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries organized in the following way, where a,b,c,d,e,f,... are arbitrary integers

```
{key1: {a: value,
        b: value,
        c: value},
 key2: {d: value,
        e: value},
 keyX: {f: valueX}}
```

What's a way (in Python 3) to get the minimum and maximum value of the keys a,b,c,d,e,f,...? Preferably as a one-liner of sorts and not a for-loop.

Comment: Can you show what the expected output looks like?

Comment: It would be the same as wanting min([a,b,c,d,e,f])

Comment: @ChristianDean that would return the minimum or maximum of the top-level keys.

Comment: @ChristianDean, not quite, as that would give me the min/max of [key1, key2...], whereas I need the min/max of [a,b,c,d,e,f...]

Comment: This seems like a case of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What you're really asking for, is how to access the second level keys, potentially get them in a list, because after that, getting the min and max of such a list is trivial.

Comment: Why not `min({subkey for key in d for subkey in d[key]})`

Comment: @Antimony, yes you are correct. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: @Graytr Ah, I missed the fact that your dictionary was multi-leveled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following dictionary:

```
d = {1: {2: 3, 4: 5, 5: 4}, 2: {9: 10, 10: 9}}
```

You can flatten the dictionary to get the nested dictionaries' keys on the same level:

```
min(subkey for key in d for subkey in d[key])
# returns 2
```

Answer (score 3):

A nested generator comprehension will do the trick. The first pulls the dictionaries from the outer dictionary, the second pulls the keys from those.

```
dic = {key1: {a: value,
              b: value,
              c: value},
       key2: {d: value,
              e: value},
       keyX: {f: valueX}}
min(k for inner in dic.values() for k in inner.keys())
```